# How to compare data from two tables on different servers

Tags: mysql

I have the same copy of a database on two different servers (Azure and Google Cloud)

Since they're specular I guess the countrows should be the same but it's not.
I would like to do query to find which ids are on one database that aren't in the other.

I have really no idea from where to start

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: the easiest way would to write a simple progtamm and connect to both tables and compare them, but you can do also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: Export both tables to CSV (use ordering with sorting by PK). Then compare 2 text files (which must match even binary).